# My Android Studio preference do not have the maven repo

Tags: android, android-studio

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-could-not-get-resource-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-gradle-3-1-0-gradle-3-1-0-pom/26734/7

in there he check the maven option:

[image: ven]

this is mine, do not have the maven option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google has been [promoting the use of maven.google.com for support library and similar dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven) since I/O 2017. Use of the embedded Maven repository has been discouraged as a result, and is generally only required if you need to access [old library versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#offline-google-maven) not available via maven.google.com.

My guess is that the option you are looking for has been removed from a recent version of Android Studio (3.5?) now that most people have transitioned to maven.google.com.

Comment: What do you mean of `now that most people have transitioned to maven.google.com`?

Comment: By that I mean: most people have added the `google()` Maven repo to their Gradle `repositories` block, and are fetching the support library and similar dependencies from the repo hosted at maven.google.com, rather than fetching those same dependencies from the embedded Maven repo that's part of an Android SDK installation.